# Getting Specific Number of Days With Moment.js, Node npm and Handlbars

Tags: node.js, npm, handlebars.js, momentjs

I am using moment.js in node Handlebars.  I found this helper: http://moment.handlebars.solidgoldpig.com/ and it's been useful but I would like to be able to calculate the number of days between now and a specific date in the future and return the answer in days.

`{{moment "12/10/2018" "from" dfrom}}` returns "22 days".  `{{moment "12/25/2018" "from" dfrom}}` returns "in a month".  What I want is "38 days".

I can't figure out what needs to change in handlebars to accomplish this. I would appreciate any and all suggestions.

To follow through and provide a detailed explanation of what worked for me, I'm adding to this question.  But essentially Marcos Casagrande's answer should be the accepted answer.

1. I installed momentjs by from the command line `npm install moment --save`
2. In server.js I added `var moment = require("moment");
3. Then I copied Marcos Casagrande's answer into server.js, but added a bit of precision to the calculation. `return Math.abs(moment().startOf('day').diff(moment(date).startOf('day'), 'days')+1);`
4. In my handlebars view I used `{{days-diff "2018-12-25 00:00"}}`
5. I did not add moment.js in the html file's head.

Comment: This might be helpful... https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: @dward, Thank you.  What I'm having a challenge with is using moment.js with Handlebars.

Comment: Are you not able to do the comparison or diff on the server? What if you mutated or mapped the array before the handlebars loop? Not sure what your constraints are. If client side, consider mapping your array or modifying object prior to binding or looping.

Comment: Thanks again @dward.  because I'm new to this I wasn't entirely clear what code to put where.  Marcos Casagrande's answer below got be on the right track.

Comment: No need to exclaim that you're new, we all start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a few lines of code:

All you need is: `dateA.diff(dateB, 'days'));`

```js
moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;

Handlebars.registerHelper('days-diff', date => {
  return Math.abs(moment().diff(moment(date), 'days'));
});

const template = Handlebars.compile(`
  Until 12/10/2018: {{days-diff "12/10/2018"}}
  Until 12/25/2018: {{days-diff "12/25/2018"}}
  Until 12/25/2019: {{days-diff "12/25/2019"}}
`);

console.log(template());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Handlebars</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.8/handlebars.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```